# Fallo en la replicacion maestro-esclavo en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, base-de-datos, wamp, mysqldb

Me surgió un problema con la replicación Maestro-Esclavo en MySQL (estoy usando wampserver y la versión es 5.7.36). Sucede que realicé todos los pasos de replicación (o eso creo) incluyendo la configuración en my.ini. Al comprobar el estado del esclavo, sale todo correcto, entonces realicé una acción en el maestro y lo pude visualizar en el esclavo, sin embargo al realizar una segunda acción en el maestro, ya no se sincroniza con el esclavo y por ende no se puede visualizar los cambios que se hagan; y desde ahí ya no funciona la sincronización entre Maestro-Esclavo, a pesar de eso al comprobar el estado del esclavo sale todo correcto y se actualiza la posición con el maestro.

**Aquí les dejo la configuración del my.ini del Maestro:**

```
; MySQL config file.
;
; MySQL programs look for option files in a set of
; locations which depend on the deployment platform.
; You can copy this option file to one of those
; locations. For information about these locations, see:
; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/option-files.html
;
; In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
; If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
; with the "--help" option.

; The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
;password = your_password
port =3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

; Here follows entries for some specific programs

; The MySQL server
[wampmysqld64]
;skip-grant-tables
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
port =3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 1M

;Added to reduce memory used (minimum is 400)
table_definition_cache = 600

sort_buffer_size = 2M
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
;Path to mysql install directory
basedir="c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.36"
log-error="c:/wamp64/logs/mysql.log"
;Verbosity Value  1 Errors only, 2  Errors and warnings , 3 Errors, warnings, and notes
log_error_verbosity=2
;Path to data directory
datadir="c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.36/data"

;Path to the language
;See Documentation:
; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-message-language.html
lc-messages-dir="c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.36/share"
lc-messages=en_US

; Default storage engine that will be used if the engine is not specified when creating tables.
; This does not prevent the creation of InnoDB tables, just specify ENGINE=InnoDB
default-storage-engine=MYISAM
;default-storage-engine=InnoDB

;To avoid warning messages
secure_file_priv="c:/wamp64/tmp"
skip-ssl

explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=true

; Set the SQL mode to strict
;sql-mode=""
sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"

; Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
; if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
; All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
; Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
; (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
;
;skip-networking

; Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

; Replication Master Server (default)
; binary logging is required for replication
; log-bin=mysql-bin

; binary logging format - mixed recommended
; binlog_format=mixed

; required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
; defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
; but will not function as a master if omitted
;server-id = 1

; Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)

; New for MySQL 5.6 if no slave
skip-slave-start

;
; To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
; two methods :
;
; 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
;    the syntax is:
;
;    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
;    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
;
;    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
;    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
;
;    Example:
;
;    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
;    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
;
; OR
;
; 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
;    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
;    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
;    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
;    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
;    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
;    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
;    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
;    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
;
; required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
; (and different from the master)
; defaults to 2 if master-host is set
; but will not function as a slave if omitted
;server-id       = 2
;
; The replication master for this slave - required
;master-host     =   <hostname>
;
; The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
; to the master - required
;master-user     =   <username>
;
; The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
; the master - required
;master-password =   <password>
;
; The port the master is listening on.
; optional - defaults to 3306
;master-port     =  <port>
;
; binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
;log-bin=mysql-bin

; Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
;tmpdir   = /tmp/
;log-update   = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

; The InnoDB tablespace encryption feature relies on the keyring_file
; plugin for encryption key management, and the keyring_file plugin
; must be loaded prior to storage engine initialization to facilitate
; InnoDB recovery for encrypted tables. If you do not want to load the
; keyring_file plugin at server startup, specify an empty string.
early-plugin-load=""

innodb-adaptive-hash-index=on
innodb-buffer-pool-dump-now=off
innodb-buffer-pool-dump-at-shutdown=off
innodb-buffer-pool-instances=2
innodb-buffer-pool-load-at-startup=off
innodb-buffer-pool-size=1G
innodb-data-file-path=ibdata1:12M:autoextend:max:500M
innodb-default-row-format=compact
innodb-doublewrite=on
;skip-innodb_doublewrite
innodb-file-per-table=1
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=1
innodb-flush-method=normal
;innodb-force-recovery=1
innodb-ft-enable-stopword=off
innodb-ft-max-token-size=10
innodb-ft-min-token-size=0
innodb-io-capacity=2000
innodb-max-dirty-pages-pct=90
innodb-lock-wait-timeout=600
innodb-log-buffer-size=16M
innodb-log-file-size=20M
innodb-log-files-in-group=2
innodb-max-dirty-pages-pct=80
innodb-optimize-fulltext-only=1
innodb-page-size=16K
innodb-purge-threads=10
innodb-read-io-threads=10
innodb-stats-on-metadata=0
;innodb-strict-mode=off
innodb-thread-concurrency=16
innodb-undo-log-truncate=on
innodb-write-io-threads=4

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
; Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
;safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer_size = 2M
write_buffer_size = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size_size = 20M
read_buffer_size = 2M
write_buffer_size = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=1
binlog_do_db=unidad
sync_binlog=1
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
port =3306
```

**Aquí les dejo la configuración del my.ini del Esclavo:**

```
# Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
# other programs (such as a web server)
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:\mysql\data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
user = "esclavito"
password    = "123"
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
bind-address = 192.168.100.14
replicate_do_db=Unidad
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data

lc-messages-dir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/share

# Change your locale here !
lc-messages=fr_FR

# Avoid warning
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking

# Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

#Replication Master Server (default)
#binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog_do_db=unidad

#binary logging format - mixed recommended
binlog_format=mixed

#required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
#defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
#but will not function as a master if omitted
#server-id  = 2

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)


# New for MySQL 5.6 if no slave
skip-slave-start

#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   '192.168.100.3'
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  3306
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
log-bin=mysql-bin

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir     = /tmp/     
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_log_arch_dir = C:\mysql\data/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=2
user = "esclavito"
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
port=3306
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!